# How to convert parameter type into a different object type

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm doing some scripting in PowerShell, and I was wondering if there's a way to "declare" a parameter "X" the same way parameter "-Credential" is declared, for example in Get-WMIObject cmdlet.

Let me be more specific. The Credential parameter in almost all cmdlets is a PSCredential Object. But, the argument can be either a PSCredential Object or, a String Object with the username.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ([Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
       [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
       $Credential)
```

The problem comes when passing a string. Of course, an argument transformation on the parameter cannot be done. Cannot convert the type "System.String" into a type PSCrendential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
param(
    [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
    $Credential=[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty
)
```

As to parameter argument transformation, check this awesome script:

http://poshcode.org/3024

Comment: I've always used `if ($Credential.GetType().Name -ne 'PSCredential') {$Credential = Get-Credential $Credential}` in the body of the function (casting $Credential as [PSObject]). Your solution is more elegant, thanks! However, what does the `=[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty` accomplish? Just `[System.Management.Automation.Credential()]$Credential` by itself seems to work just as well - if you supply a string, you get a PS Credential Request prompt with the "User name" field populated with the string.

Comment: 1/2 When the Credential parameter is PSCredential, you cannot pass a string to it:
get-something -cred adi, you'll get a ' Cannot process argument transformation' error. 
using the 'Credential()' transformation solves this. Now  you can do 'get-something -cred adi' and the have the credential dialog invoked and populated with the username.

Comment: 2/2 One use I have found when setting the valye to [PSCredential]::Empty is when you pass the credetial to a function that uses a wmi cmdlet.
WMI doesn't allow 'user credentials cannot for local connections', so you had to do an IF inside your function, finding if credentails has been passes and the local computer is the target.
With [PSCredential]::Empty you can just pass $credential and get away with it. Hope that was clear enough.

Comment: FYI: PoshCode link seems to be broken... This is a useful list on how auto-conversion works though: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/

Answer (score 1):

A bit more of info :)

PowerShell has one of these argument transformations included for use with credentials, so whenever you write a script that has a PSCredential parameter, you should decorate it with the CredentialAttribute like this:

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
      [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
      [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]$Credential =  [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty)
```

That one’s a little confusing because you leave off the “Attribute” part of the attribute’s name (ie: you don’t have to specify [[System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.credentialattribute)), so at first glance, it looks like you’re specifying the Credential type twice. Of course, in reality this is another use of parenthesis in PowerShell. To specify an attribute, you use square braces as with types, but with parenthesis in them (even if the attribute doesn’t require any parameters).

http://huddledmasses.org/more-custom-attributes-for-powershell-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a function parameter to have type [T], when you invoke the function you can supply any object of type [X] where [T] has a single-parameter constructor that takes type [X].

In other words, if you can construct a [T] from a [String], you can invoke the function with either a [T] or a [String].

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it. I declare the parameter like this:

[Parameter(Position=2)]
[object]$Credential

Then at the beginning of the script:

```
begin {
        Write-Verbose -Message "Starting  $($myinvocation.mycommand)"
        write-verbose -Message "Using volume $($volume.toUpper())"
        #convert credential to a PSCredential if a string was passed.
        if ( $credential -is [system.management.automation.psCredential]) {
            Write-Verbose "Using PSCredential for $($credential.username)"
        }
        ElseIf ($Credential) {
            Write-Verbose "Getting PSCredential for $credential"
            $Credential=Get-Credential $credential
        }
    } #Begin
```